# Modify values of one dataframe using other dataframe as query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'name': ["John", "Mark", "Alice", "Alice"], 'age': [18, 23, 23, 27], 'luckynumber': [10, 20, 30, 40]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'name': ["Alice"], 'age': ['23']})

>>> df1
   age  luckynumber   name
0   18           10   John
1   23           20   Mark
2   23           30  Alice
3   27           40  Alice

>>> df2
  age   name
0  23  Alice
```

I'd like to set the `luckynumber` for `df1` entries which have a match with `df2` to `-1`. I don't want to change the layout of `df1`. I was hoping something like `df1[df2]['luckynumber'] = -1` would work, but it doesn't.

The expected output would be:

```
>>> df1
   age  luckynumber   name
0   18           10   John
1   23           20   Mark
2   23           -1  Alice
3   27           40  Alice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column `age` for integer columns in both DataFrames, then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with parameter `indicator=True` with left join and check `both` for boolean mask, last set value by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df2['age'] = df2['age'].astype(int)

mask = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'] == 'both'

df1.loc[mask, 'luckynumber'] = -1
print (df1)
    name  age  luckynumber
0   John   18           10
1   Mark   23           20
2  Alice   23           -1
3  Alice   27           40
```

Comment: Doh. I accidentally made the age a string when creating example data, it was meant to be integer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most optimal solution, but this works

1. Create a indicator column called `value`, which indicates when there was a match.
2. Merge the two dataframes based on keys `age` and `name`
3. Then use `np.where` to check conditionally if there was a match and change the value of column `luckynumber`

```
df2['value'] = 1

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['age', 'name'], right_on=['age', 'name'], how='left')

df3['luckynumber'] = np.where(df3.value == 1, -1, df1.luckynumber)

df3.drop('value', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
    age luckynumber name
0   18  10          John
1   23  20          Mark
2   23  -1          Alice
3   27  40          Alice
```